# Encrypt from Java and decrypt in PHP (RIJNDAEL)

Tags: java, php, rijndael

I have to connect from a Java Desktop application and Android app to a Webservice. I need to send the login encrypted with RIJNDAEL but I am experiencing problems.

Code in Java:

```
public static String getEncryptedLogin(String loginID, String encryptionKey) {
    byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "RIJNDAEL");

    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
    byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(loginID.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result);
}
```

And called this way.

```
String dataToSend = "login="+Testencrypted.getEncryptedLogin(LOGIN,WS_ENCKEY)+"&language=en";
```

On WS_ENCKEY is a String with key (32chars) for encryption.

When I execute the Java code I get an Exception error "Illegal Key Size", so after reading in others post in this website, RIJNDAEL needs a 128 bit key, so I change the way I call encryption method to

```
String dataToSend = "login="+Testencrypted.getEncryptedLogin(LOGIN,WS_ENCKEY.substring(0,16))+"&language=en";
```

On Server side I have this PHP code to decrypt:

```
<?php
class Encrypter {
    public static function encrypt($text,$key) {
        $textenc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        return base64_encode($textenc);
    }
    public static function decrypt($text,$key) {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
}
```

In server I receive the correct data, but when I try to decrypt the login, the output is not the same.

I can't change the code on server side, can you help me?

Comment: PHP mcrypt does not support PKCS5 padding. It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

PHP mcrypt does not support PKCS5 padding, only null padding. You will have to select no padding in Java and null pad the input data on encryption to a multiple of the block size and remove the nulls on decryption in Java.

The PHP mcrypt server code is using ECB mode which is insecure, to be compatible  Java will also need to specify ECB mode, not CBC mode. ECB mode does not use an IV.